# CGRect in Swift 3 rotating with correct origin

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cgaffinetransform, cgrect

I'm trying to rotate a line (thin rectangle) around its endpoint.  I have it working fine, but step 2 is to shorten the line and have it still rotate around the endpoint (center of rotation).

```
    // Create and add a colored square
var rod = UIView()
var countsteps = 0
var Mass = 1
var Radius = 1.00
let rectWidth = screenWidth * 0.5
let rectVertical = screenHeight * 0.5
let rectLeft = screenWidth * 0.5

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // set background color to blue
    rod.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 145/255, green: 170/255, blue: 157/255, alpha: 1)
    //rod Line
    rod.frame = CGRect(x: rectLeft, y: rectVertical, width: 3, height: rectWidth)
    // finally, add the square to the screen
    self.view.addSubview(rod)

    //Create Timer
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(Acceleration.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


func update() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {

        //Slope Line
        let rectSize = CGFloat(self.Radius) * self.rectWidth / 100
        let amountRotation = CGFloat(CGFloat(self.countsteps)/57.3)
        let originPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
        self.rod.layer.anchorPoint = originPoint
        self.rod.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: amountRotation)
        self.countsteps = self.countsteps + 1
        if (self.countsteps > 359) {
            self.countsteps = 0
        }
    })
}
```

I tried adding this line:

```
self.rod.frame.size = CGSize(width: 3.00, height: rectSize)
```

But, that makes the box rotate while changing proportions around a different axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line:

```
self.rod.layer.position = originPoint
```

so, your update func looks like:

```
    func update() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {

            //Slope Line
            let rectSize = CGFloat(self.Radius) * self.rectWidth / 100
            let amountRotation = CGFloat(CGFloat(self.countsteps)/57.3)
            let originPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
            self.rod.layer.anchorPoint = originPoint
            self.rod.layer.position = originPoint
            self.rod.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: amountRotation)
            self.countsteps = self.countsteps + 1
            if (self.countsteps > 359) {
                self.countsteps = 0
            }
        })
    }
```

I seriously recommend adding some color to layers and views background, with some alpha, it is quite useful to detect what the system is doing, like a visual debug.